# How to query a NextJS route handler from a server component and get data from Supabase

Tags: next.js, supabase

Whenever I try to fetch data from my route handler from within a server component in NextJS, the query is made by the server, therefor the route handler returns this error : `{ error: 'JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned' }`

When I try to query my route handler 'manually' I have no issues because I have my `supabase-auth-token` set. So the `createRouteHandlerSupabaseClient` in the routeHandler have no issues.

But when the server does I think it can't be authentified as "me".
To specify, I have correctly set the prerequisites from the supabase documentation [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs-server-components). I am using NextJS 13 and the 'app' directory.

/app/api/customroute/[id]/page.jsx

```js
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.HOST}/api/customroute/` + params.id)
    const test = await res.json()
    console.log(test)
```

/app/customotherroute/[id]/route.js

```js
export async function GET(req, { params }) {
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerSupabaseClient({
        headers,
        cookies
    });
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('table')
        .select('*,other_table(column)')
        .eq('id', params.id)
    if (error == null) {
        return NextResponse.json({ data });
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message });
}
```

I can go back to fecthing data using a `createServerComponentSupabaseClient` directly in my server component but for the sake of code replication I would prefer to use an API.
Is there something I am missing ?

I have tried to set the user data in the route handler using `const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser()`  but it did not work.

Comment: Are you fetching the data in a client or server component?

Comment: As I’ve written I’m fetching data from within a server component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of digging, I found the (obvious) answer to this.
This is currently a bug in NextJS.
The cookies are not correctly passed by the server when calling a routehandler. So the cookies list is empty.
This is documented in this youtube video from supabase.
https://youtu.be/KmJN-bEayeY?t=600
The current workaround is to implement the query inside the server component.

Comment: from my understanding - someone correct me - but route handlers are only meant to be called from a CLIENT component.  The whole purpose is to be able to make server calls  from the CLIENT. So calling a route handler from the server wont work.  If you're calling data on the server, just use a normal async fetch.

Comment: In that case, how can we cache the supabase responses? I was trying to do this so I can use fetch (with caching) in the RSC. Nextjs is not cacheing my supabase calls in RSCs